# Python ElementTree "no element found" exception

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, elementtree

Good day everybody.

I'm trying to read, parse and use an xml-file using ElementTree.
Following data:

```
<level>
    <leveldata>
        <level name="hh" difficulty="Easy" lenght="3600">
            <meteorite chance="4" speed="3" >
                <image id="1">
                <image id="2">
                <image id="3">
            <meteorite />
            <meteorite chance="4" speed="3" >
                <image id="4">
                <image id="5">
                <image id="6">
            <meteorite />
        <level />
    <leveldata />
    <meteorimages>
        <meteor id="5" imagepath="res\meteorit_1.png">
        <meteor id="5" imagepath="res\meteorit_2.png">
        <meteor id="5" imagepath="res\meteorit_3.png">
    <meteorimages />
<datasheet />
<level />
```

Sadly, I ElementTree gives an exception!!! Reading the file with following code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
***code***
tree = ET.parse("res\\data.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
```

Exception:

```
File "E:\blabla\core.py", line 26, in load_levelproperties
    *tree = ET.parse("res\\data.xml")*   File "E:\Programme(x86)\Python2.7x86\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line
1182, in parse
    *tree.parse(source, parser)*   File "E:\Programme(x86)\Python2.7x86\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line
657, in parse
    *self._root = parser.close()*   File "E:\Programme(x86)\Python2.7x86\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line
1654, in close
    *self._raiseerror(v)*   File "E:\Programme(x86)\Python2.7x86\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line
1506, in _raiseerror
    ***raise err xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: no element found: line 16, column 9***
```

I can't figure out what's wrong, I've tried to change data.xml in every possible way I can imagine, no difference. It's always the last line of the file!
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your tags are not closed properly.  For example, to close a "meteorite" tag, use `</meteorite>` not `<meteorite />`.

Answer (score 7):

You XML is not well-formed, `ElementTree` cannot parse it - it really looks like it is a part of a real document.

Here's what you get if you format it:

```
<level>
    <leveldata>
        <level name="hh" difficulty="Easy" lenght="3600">
            <meteorite chance="4" speed="3">
                <image id="1">
                    <image id="2">
                        <image id="3">
                            <meteorite/>
                            <meteorite chance="4" speed="3">
                                <image id="4">
                                    <image id="5">
                                        <image id="6">
                                            <meteorite/>
                                            <level/>
                                            <leveldata/>
                                            <meteorimages>
                                                <meteor id="5" imagepath="res\meteorit_1.png">
                                                    <meteor id="5" imagepath="res\meteorit_2.png">
                                                        <meteor id="5" imagepath="res\meteorit_3.png">
                                                            <meteorimages/>
                                                            <datasheet/>
                                                            <level/>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "format"?
How should I do it better?

Comment: @user3424423 I've just indented the xml so it is easier to see that the xml is not correctly structured. Elementtree cannot handle it.

Comment: This does not help me at all. What do I have to do better?

Comment: To clarify the above old answer for anyone stumbling upon it now:
The 'close' tags are wrong <tag/> instead of </tag> - This creates a NEW tag, nested under the one that was expected to be closed, rather than closing it.

Moving the / to the front of the tag name will correct part of the issue, plus adding close tags for the other entries.

Answer (score 0):

I face similar issues in the past but if you clearly see all the open tags in the messy file and its counter closing tags with </> syntax, it is usually the main issue with xml files.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31786299)